# Using CSS Peek in React

Tags: css, reactjs

is there a way of using CSS Peek in *.js files, specifically in React components.

If not, is there any extension that allows me to see inline CSS styling for selected **className**?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an old [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49118) - CSS Peek doesn't provide built-in support for jumping to css from jsx code. However, I have also not found any extension in the marketplace for this.

Comment: It's been fixed since then. The latest version of CSS Peek now supports peeking from JSX :)

Comment: Great, thanks @PranayPrakash

Answer (score 2):

Author here. Please update to the latest version of CSS Peek (v4.3.5). It now supports .js and .jsx files by default

Comment: does it also support `.tsx` files?

Answer (score 0):

Initial support is shiping in version 2.2.0
([More information](https://github.com/pucelle/vscode-css-navigation/issues/1))